# How to unit test nested for loop function in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to unit test a function with nested for loop using the Mock module in Python:

main.py:

```
@dataclass
Helper_class():
  Attr1: Set[some_object]
  Attr2: Set[str]

def fetch_rule_for(api, id):
    return some rule_objects based on id

def my_func(list_ids):
    api = create some api connection
    result_dict = dict()
    for id in list_ids:
      Attr1_set = set()
      Attr2_set = set()
      for rule in fetch_rule_for(api, id):
        if any(a.name == 'some_action_name' for a in rule.actions):
          Attr2_set.add(rule.attr1)
          Attr1_set.add(rule)
      result_dict[id] = Helper_class(Attr1_set, Attr2_set)

    return result_dict
```

Rule is a class object with method actions, action is another class object with attribute name.

Two questions I'm struggling with:

(1) How do I pacth the return value of function fetch_rule_for(api, id) where the return is a complicated class object?

(2) How do I deal with the for loops in Python using unit test? I have seen mock.call_count mentioned but can someone please get into more details or point me to relevant resources?

I'm new to unit testing in Python so any help is much appreicated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to patch the return value of a class just instantiate the class and manually set any necessary class variables then it's just a matter of using `configure_mock(return_value=class_object)`

Here is an example with requests.Response:

```
    resp = Response()
    resp.status_code = 200
    resp._content = json.dumps({'token': 'xyz123'})
    mock_post.configure_mock(return_value=resp)
```

In the case of the for loop you likely want to mock any returns contained within using `side_effect`

```
@mock.patch('your_class.fetch_rule_for', side_effect=iter([1,2,3]))
```

Comment: The class I'm trying to patch takes in quite a lot variables to instantiate, which is what i'm trying to avoid. For example, some of the variables are nested dictionaries with incredibly long strings.  Is there any way to go around that?

Comment: Do you need the class in the current test? If not you can just patch the function to return exactly what you want or the minimally viable object needed to proceed with the remainder of the test.